# FOS Open Sans font for cyrillic in latest TexLive

Tags: fonts, cyrillic

Recently, I compile my old documets and discovered TexLive2019 does not recognize
`fos`- Open Sans font for cyrillic. How can I still use `fos` or any similar font?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian, ukrainian]{babel}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fos}

\begin{document}

    \sffamily ІЄЄ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not using `\usepackage{opensans}` to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the package renamed the font families. Either use the package opensans, or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian, ukrainian]{babel}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{opensans-LF}
    \sffamily ІЄЄ 123

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{opensans-OsF}
    \sffamily ІЄЄ 123    


\end{document}
```

[image]